# How to modify AppShell.xaml in MAUI?

Tags: maui

This is my code in AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="DemoParent.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DemoParent.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Title="DemoParent">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab 
            Icon="icon_X.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:X}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab 
            Icon="icon_Y.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Y}" />
        </Tab> 
        <Tab 
            Icon="icon_Z.png" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Z}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab 
            Icon="icon_W.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:W}" />
        </Tab> 
        <Tab
            Icon="icon_r.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:R}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Basically, when I run the app, then the first tab where icon = "icon_X.png" is selected by default.

I want that when I run the app, then instead of the first tab being selected automatically, it will select the third tab, where icon = "icon_Z.png", by default.

And Secondly, how can I animate tabs on click/touch?

Comment: Please don't "shout" (using all caps is irritating and difficult to read)

Comment: @Julian sorry sir but i didn't get it.

Comment: It's difficult to read WHEN THE TEXT IS ALL IN CAPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the `CurrentItem` to achieve this.

Please first add  `x:Name` for the view `Z`(e.g. `x:Name="zPage"`),just as follows:

```
    <Tab 
        Icon="icon_Z.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Z}" x:Name="zPage" />
    </Tab>
```

Then,set the `CurrentItem` to `zPage`

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       //set the CurrentItem to zPage
        CurrentItem = zPage;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes jessie it working as expected. Thanks for answer I thought or may dreamed or what not sure I already commented on your answer.. When the day you answered not sure may it got deleted or what..

Comment: I am new sir, I don't know how to mark question as answered..I think only moderators can do that isn't it?

Comment: As long as the person asking the question can mark other's answer as accepted if someone else's answer helps solve the problem. For more information, please check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).  :)